# Regex in R, matching strings

Tags: r, regex, string

I have strings like this: "X96HE6.10nMBI_1_2", "X96HE6.10nMBI_2_2", "X96HE6.10nMBI_3_2" and I would like to match only numbers 1, 2 and 3 in between underscores but without them(underscores). The best solution I could come up with is this `str_match(sample_names, "_+[1-3]?")` I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: `str_match(sample_names,"(?<=_)\\d+(?=_)")`

Comment: @Onyambu Thank you very much! :) Just a question, do you maybe know some good tutorial or some exercises on web, for practicing regex in R?

Comment: Do you wish to match only the digits `'1'`, `'2'` or `'3'`, and only when they are surrounded by underscores, or match any single digit surrounded by underscores or match any string of digits surrounded by underscores? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: Apologies @Cary Swoveland, I have added "only" to my question, I was interested only in digits '1', '2', '3' between two underscores. But I already got my answer, sorry if I caused you any inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method is by using `sub`and backreference:

Data:

```
d <- c("X96HE6.10nMBI_1_2", "X96HE6.10nMBI_2_2", "X96HE6.10nMBI_3_2")
```

Solution:

```
sub(".*_(\\d)_.*", "\\1", d)
```

Here, `(\\d)` defines the capturing group for a single number (if the number in question can be more than one digit, use `\\d+`) that is 'recalled' by the backreference `\\1`in `sub`s replacement argument

Alternatively use `str_extract` and positive lookaround:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(d, "(?<=_)\\d(?=_)")
```

`(?<=_)` is positive lookbehind which can be glossed as "If you see `_` on the left..."

`\\d` is the number to be matched

`(?=_)` is positive lookahead, which can be glossed as "If you see `_` on the right..."

Result:

```
[1] "1" "2" "3"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Look Arounds, I personally rely heavily on the stringr Cheatsheets for these kind of regex, the syntax is a bit hard to remember, here is the [rstudio page for Cheatsheets](https://rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/) look for stringr ->LOOK AROUNDS

```r
library(tidyverse)

codes <- c("X96HE6.10nMBI_1_2", "X96HE6.10nMBI_2_2", "X96HE6.10nMBI_3_2")

codes %>%
  str_extract("(?<=_)[:digit:]+(?=_)")
#> [1] "1" "2" "3"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice! :)

Answer (score 1):

No need for any third-party module:

```
strings <- c("X96HE6.10nMBI_1_2", "X96HE6.10nMBI_2_2", "X96HE6.10nMBI_3_2")
pattern <- "(?<=_)(\\d+)(?=_)"

unlist(regmatches(strings, gregexpr(pattern, strings, perl = TRUE)))
```

Which yields:

```
[1] "1" "2" "3"
```

Comment: That's not the expected output of the OP: "I would like to match numbers 1, 2 and 3 in between underscores"

Comment: `(?!$)(?=_)` =  `(?=_)` because `_` is not the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Using `x` in the Note at the end, read it in using `read.table` and pick off the second field.  No packages or regular expressions are used.

```
read.table(text = x, sep = "_")[[2]]
## [1] 1 2 3
```

### Note

```
x <- c("X96HE6.10nMBI_1_2", "X96HE6.10nMBI_2_2", "X96HE6.10nMBI_3_2")
```